# Do I need layoutIfNeeded() or kCAGravityResize for my CALayer?

Tags: ios, swift

I have successfully started a session on a sublayer but the video looks like this. Do I need to add self.view.layoutIfNeeded() somewhere? If so where can I put it? I've put it in a few different areas but no go. Should I be using something called kCAGravityResize? My goal is to have the video on its own layer filling half screen and then have a tableView layer for graphics  text etc filling the other half of the screen. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To debug this you can give the preview layer a background color. This allows you to see where the layer is, and where the video on that layer is.

I don't know your exact view hierarchy but the problem here is often that the view resizes, but the preview layer keeps the same frame.

You can subclass your view and update the preview layer's frame in `layoutSublayersOfLayer:`.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to programming. This is my first medium app so I'm not really following you :(  I thought the preview layer is already purple? How would I give it a bg color? Did you see my view hierarchy in the screen shot? I thought I already subclassed with the CALayer method? Could you please give some example code? using my property and variable names? Please see my full code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have got it working using viewLayer.masksToBounds. The video preview now follows the size I set for the UIImageView.